# How to get base enum name in Dynamics AX?

Tags: enums, axapta

I would like get in code name of base enum not value or label.
With this code I get label not name:

```
info(enum2str(AssetGroup::AssetGroup1));
```

Comment: Check this http://arsalanax.blogspot.com/2012/02/get-values-of-base-enums-using-code-in.html and http://bmdax.blogspot.com/2010/08/outputting-name-of-enum-element-instead.html

Comment: Thanks! http://bmdax.blogspot.com/2010/08/outputting-name-of-enum-element-instead.html helps me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use `enum2Symbol()`

*For example:*

```
enum2Symbol(enumNum(KPAssetGroup), KPAssetGroup::PWNiP);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this as follows.

1 - Declare a `EnumId` variable.

2 - Declare a `dictEnum` variable.

3 - Declare a `int` variable.

4 - Use `index2Symbol` method of `dictEnum` to get code name of base enum.

*Optional - Use `index2Label` method of `dictEnum` to get label of base enum.*

***Code example:***

```
static void StackOverflow(Args _args)
{    
    EnumId   Id        = enumNum(SalesType);
    DictEnum dictEnum  = new DictEnum(Id);
    int      EnumValue = enum2Int(SalesType::Journal); //Replace Base enum for Your Base Enum.

    info(dictEnum.index2Symbol(EnumValue));  
    //info(dictEnum.index2Label(EnumValue)); //Optional only reference   
}
```